# Combine two Functions in Google Sheet as STRING Parameter

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am getting Formula Parse error. Help me with Combining 2 Formula. Here IMPORTRANGE has two String Parameter

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1Iyxg6vcnAR8zHpJaThfdP7UhdiMwFTbOwrW0l_II83M",QUERY(MAINTAINANCE!A5:K151; "select * where Col7 is not null Order By Col7",0))
```

Here my second Formula QUERY needs to convert in to string using &" but i dont know how to please help me

I Have Try to Using "& to pass both Functions as STRIG. Because IMPORTRANGE has two Parameter as String For Example..

```
IMPORTRANGE(URL_ADDRESS,RANGE AS STRING)
```

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("1Iyxg6vcnAR8zHpJaThfdP7UhdiMwFTbOwrW0l_II83M"; 
 SINGLE(QUERY(MAINTAINANCE!A5:K151; "where Col7 is not null order by Col7"; 0)))
```

will work but only if output from your QUERY is range or cell. example:

```
A1

A1:A10

Sheet1!A1:A10
```